# Aptana sftp connection failed

Tags: aptana, sftp, aptana3

I'm trying to connect to a sftp but I'm getting an error:
Establishing sfpt connection failed: the host signature is invalid or the host key was not accepted.
Any idea how to make this work? I'm using filezilla and fugu just fine. It's just aptana that's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and I was getting the same error in OS X (you didn't specify OS though). In my case it was objecting because I had spun up a new server so the remote server's ssh signature had changed, hence the "*the host signature is invalid*".

If you go to `Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> SSH2` there is a tab for *Known Hosts* which appears to be populated from the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

This is a list of remote host signatures and you should find your remote host in this list.

There is a *Remove* button here which will remove the host from the list but bringing up the dialog again shows it hasn't been removed at all!

It looks like the list is populated at startup and the *Remove* button is not functional. The only way I could get this to work was to:

- Edit the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file outside of Aptana and delete the particular host key.
- Restart Aptana

Comment: I don't know which version you were using, but I just installed the latest release (3.4.2) and the `remove` button you mentioned is there and functional. I had moved my website to a new host and this solution proved successful.